# maven-antrun-plugin doesn't scp work

Tags: jar, jboss, soa

Hy All,

I Have a problem with maven-antrun-plugin scp task, and I would like to solve it. I develop on windows 7 professional.

apache-ant-1.9.2 is installed. ANT_HOME is set to c:\apache\apache-ant-1.9.2. ant-jsch.jar can be found in ANT_HOME\lib.

apache-maven-3.1.1 is installed. M2_HOME is set to c:\apache\apache-maven-3.1.1 and M2_REPO is set to c:\Users\admin.m2.

I would like to copy a jar file to lib directory of a remote server.

Here is the snippet from the pom.xml:

```
<host>x.x.x.x</host>
    <username>xxx</username>
    <password>xxx</password>

    <jbossesb.home>/home/${username}/jboss-soa-p-5/jboss-as</jbossesb.home>
    <jbossesb.server.name>xxx</jbossesb.server.name>
    <jbossesb.version>4.12</jbossesb.version>
    <ant.home>${env.ANT_HOME}</ant.home>
```

...

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <taskdef name="scp"
                                classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp"
                                classpathref="${ant.home}\lib\ant-jsch.jar" />
                            <scp
                                todir="${username}:${password}@${host}:${jbossesb.home}/server/${jbossesb.server.name}/lib"
                                trust="yes"
                                verbose="yes">
                                <fileset dir="target"
                                    includes="${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar" />
                            </scp>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I use the command `mvn clean install` I get the following:

[INFO] Executing tasks

[INFO] Executed tasks

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD SUCCESS

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

And then it occurs nothing. It doesn't connect to server and doesn't copy my jar to remote server.

Please, help me someone.

Comment: please refer the project...and even clean the project..

Comment: I don't understand. Please tell me verbose.

Comment: Try running it `mvn -X clean install` to see if Verbose mode prints out more.

Comment: sorry it is refresh...the project..